# Text obtained with innerHTML dissapear

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following code:

```js
function passVerif() {
  if (document.forms['form'].pass.value === "") {
    messagePV.innerHTML = ("Password field is empty!")
    //alert("Password field is empty!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function emailVerif() {
  if (document.forms['form'].email.value === "") {
    messageEV.innerHTML = ("Email field is empty!")
    //alert("Email field is empty!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validate() {
  var email = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
    messageV.innerHTML = ("Please enter a valid e-mail address!")
    //alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form name="form"> Login<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email here" id="input" class="input">Email address<br>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter password here" class="input">Password<br>
    <input type="button" name="required" onclick="return passVerif(), emailVerif(), validate()">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="messagePV"></div>
<div id="messageEV"></div>
<div id="messageV"></div>
```

As you can see, input type is `submit`. Because of that (page is refreshing after click on button) the text I want to show disappears after refresh.

As I read on other posts, the simple change from `submit` to `button` will do the dew.

But I am suspecting that I messed up the `return false` and `return true` instructions in all of my functions.

Is this correct? If they are in a logical way I can avoid the page refresh and continue to use `submit`? At least until all conditions are met and the form is good to go.

In other words, can someone help me to put `return false` and `true` in such way that the page will refresh only if all conditions are met.

Thanks a lot, I am not even a noob.

Codes are copied from different sources on the internet. I am at the very beginning of coding road. Please have mercy :)

Comment: try `return passVerif() && emailVerif() && validate()` then it will only return true if all 3 are true (but it will only show the first error if more than one is wrong)

Comment: Yes, that's true but I have to show an error also for the rest of the functions... If what I want is impossible, I can understand that and I am going to change `input` to `button`. I was only curious if this is possible... Thanks

Comment: have your onclick handler call one "validate()" function and move all your logic into that, to call each of the separate methods. Then get the results of all of those and decide what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it to one validation function and have a bool that is returned based on if it has errored or not:

```js
// Just have one validation function
function validate() {
  var errorMessage = '';   // build up an error message
  var email = document.forms['form'].email.value;
  var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  if (email === "") {
    errorMessage += "Email field is empty!<br>";
  } else if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {                        // this can be else if
    errorMessage += "Please enter a valid e-mail address!<br>";
  }
  
  if (document.forms['form'].pass.value === "") {
    errorMessage += "Password field is empty!<br>"
  }
  
  if (errorMessage === '') {
      return true;                                                       // return true as no error message
  } else { 
     document.getElementById('error-message').innerHTML = errorMessage;  // show error message and return false
     return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form name="form"> Login<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email here" id="input" class="input">Email address<br>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter password here" class="input">Password<br>
    <input type="submit" name="required" onclick="return validate();">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="error-message">
  <!-- CAN HAVE ONE ERROR MESSAGE DIV -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Pete. It works! As a matter of fact you used `button` but code also works with `submit` as I wanted. So thank you very much!
Now, I modified this if:
`if (errorMessage === '') {
    document.getElementById('error-message').innerHTML = "All OK";
      return true;`
so I can get an All OK message if pass and email are ok. It acts like previous. It is possible to have it's place elsewhere or this is not the good approach? Thank you again :)
I checked your answer :)

Comment: @Catalin, it's not a good approach for having an accepted message - you should just post your form if everything is okay.  If you really want an okay message then you will need to start doing ajax form posts but then you are just complicating things for the sake of an ok message - which not many people (if any - I have never seen a form that says everything is okay before it submits) do

Comment: yep, you are right, I also never seen such a message, but this was a requirement and based on your response I think it is misinterpreted or simply an error. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code and I could find the the messages were not getting updated based on the conditions. So I did few modifications to your code to display the message based on which condition fails.

HTML

```
<div>
    <form name="form"> Login<br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email here" id="input" class="input">Email address<br><br>
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter password here" class="input">Password<br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="required" value="Submit" onclick="return passVerif(), emailVerif(), validate()">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="messagePV"></div>
<div id="messageEV"></div>
<div id="messageV"></div>
```

JS

```
function passVerif() {
messagePV.innerHTML = ("")
if(document.forms['form'].pass.value === "") {
 messagePV.innerHTML = ("Password field is empty!")
    //alert("Password field is empty!");
return false;
 }
    return true;
}

function emailVerif() {
messageEV.innerHTML = ("")
  if(document.forms['form'].email.value === "") {
    messageEV.innerHTML = ("Email field is empty!")
      //alert("Email field is empty!");
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}

function validate() {
messageV.innerHTML = ("")
var email = document.getElementById("input").value;
var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
        messageV.innerHTML = ("Please enter a valid e-mail address!")
        //alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

By initializing the errormessage filed to empty sting u can maintain the fresh set of error messages.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85w7qaqx/1/

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Hey Darkness126. Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately the code does not work like I wanted to. I appreciate your help. At least I understood what's with the error-message initialization :)